# Abstract Algebra: Find a number of non-isomorphic subgroup of $S_3$

Tags: abstract-algebra, exceptional-isomorphisms

I'm having difficulty in understanding the method to find the solution for this question.

I repeat

> Question: Find the number of non-isomorphic subgroup of $S_3$

So is this the way to find the number of non-isomorphic subgroups of $S_3$? Since $S_3=\{1,(123),(132),(12),(23),(13)\}$, there are six non-isomorphic subgroups of $S_3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $S_3$ has order $6$, its subgroups must have order $1$, $2$, $3$ or $6$.
Groups of order $1$, $2$, $3$ are all cyclic. So there are $4$ non-isomorphic subgroups of $S_3$.

Comment: Oh ok now I got it. Thanks very much.